# How to find the time complexity of nested for-loop

Tags: language-agnostic, big-o, time-complexity

What is the time complexity for the nested loops shown below:

1)

```js
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j <=n; j += 2) {
        // some O(1) expressions
    }
}
```

2)

```js
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += 3) {
    for (int j = 1; j <=n; j += 3) {
        // some O(1) expressions
    }
}
```

In general:

```js
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += c) {
   for (int j = 1; j <=n; j += c) {
      // some O(1) expressions
   }
}
```

Is is really this the following?

```
O(nc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm will execute `(n / c) * (n /c)` iterations. We're dividing, because we are skipping `c` characters for each iteration. See that:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1)
```

Will have `n / 1` iterations

```
for (var i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 2)
```

Will have `n / 2` iterations

<sub>*Note that the result will be floored. That is, if `n = 3` and `c = 2`, it will execute only one time (`floor(3 / 2) == 1`)</sub>

So, we can generalize it to be

```
(n / c)2
= (n2/c2) 
= 1/c2 * n2
```

Remember that [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is only interested in the rate of change. Since `c` is a constant, it is ignored from the calculation.

So, the result is:

```
O(1/c2 * n2) = O(n2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, the inner loop has O(n) and the outer loop has O(n).  Therefore, for each iteration of the outside loop, the inner loop iterates n times (c does not matter for order of complexity and should be treated as if it is 1). If the outer loop iterates n times, the total number of iterations in the inner loop is n*n, or O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine there are 10 chairs (n here)
in one for loop you are iterating over all the chairs, let say you sit on all the chairs, so in total you need to sit 10 times to sit on all the chairs for a given loop.

Now imagine you sit on first chair and ask your friend to sit on the other chairs one by one including your chair, so in total your friend has to sit on 10 chairs.
Now you choses the second chair, and again ask you friend to sit on each chair again, so in total he again has to sit on 10 chairs.

Similarly you can choose the 3rd,4th... chair and so on, so in total your friend has to sit on 10 chairs for each of the chair you choose.

10 + 10 + ... = 100 times

which is equivalent to 10^2 = 100

So the complexity is O(n^2), where n is the number of chairs.